# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found

Tags: python, discord.py

Библиотека discord.py. Пишу код для проигрыша музыки из YouTube в голосовой канал.

```
`@client.command(brief="Plays a video, from a youtube URL")
async def play(ctx, url):
    await ctx.message.author.voice.channel.connect(reconnect=True)
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    print(voice)
    with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
    voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
    voice.is_playing()
`
```

Импорт модуля делал

```
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.
```

Я впервые работаю с чем то подобным, так что могу тупить XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FFMPEG** - .exe файл, необходимый для запуска звука. Этот экзешник запускается через Discord API.

Скачать его можно [здесь](https://ffmpeg.org/). Также можете [скачать архив](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/download/autobuild-2020-12-02-12-43/ffmpeg-N-100126-g0a5ff19643-win64-gpl.zip) *(Загрузка начнется сразу)*

В папке должно быть 3 файла: `ffmpeg.exe`, `ffplay.exe`, `ffprobe.exe`.

Запускам с явным указанием исполняемого файла `ffmpeg.exe`:

```
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="путь\\к\\файлу\\ffmpeg.exe", source = URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё работает